# Scalable and efficient location updates in laravel

Tags: laravel, google-maps, database-performance, pusher

For a delivery-service application based on laravel, I want to keep the customer updated on the current location of the driver. For this purpose, I have a lat and long column in my order table. The driver has the website open and posts his html5 geolocation to the server every, let's say, 30 seconds. The row gets updated with the new position and here comes the question. 
Will it be more efficient to
- have a Ajax request from the customer client every 30 seconds, that searches against all current orders with the customer id as key and retrieves the current location to update the maps, 
or to
- create a private Chanel with pusher, subscribe to it from the customer client and create locationUpdated events, once the driver submits his location?

My thoughts would be to use pusher, so that I don't have to do two queries (update and retrieve) for each updated location, periodically and for possibly hundreds of users at the same time. 
The disadvantage I assume to cause trouble would be the amount of channels to be maintained by the server, to make sure every client has access to updated information.

Unfortunately, I have no clue what would cause more effort to the server. Any argumentation why either of the two solutions is better than the other, or even further improvements are welcome.

Comment: Unfortunately this is is a bit of `DAE whats better?`. However, what you're asking for is a solution to bi-directional communication as opposed to long polling; so there's no question about it, websockets are the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought so, but was unsure about websockets, as I have never used them before.